# Obtaining class names of buttons

Tags: windows, vba, user-interface, button, automation

I use Excel VBA to automate an external program (so our technicians only have to press one button to set the settings of the program for their job).

I can find class names for windows, but neither WinID nor Window Detective show a class name for containing buttons. Is there a way to obtain these so I can automate clicking them? There are five buttons, but hoovering over each only returns information for its parent window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language *designed for automating the Windows GUI* and general purpose scripting.

It comes with the [AutoIt Window Info Tool](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) (\AutoIt3\AU3Info.exe) which allows you to get information from a window (that can be used to automate it), which includes:

- Window titles
- Text on the window (visible and hidden)
- Window size and position
- Contents of the status bar
- Position of the mouse pointer
- Colour of the pixels underneath the mouse pointer
- Details of the control underneath the mouse pointer

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that program is pretty nice.  Unfortunately it still couldn't get what I'm looking for.  The buttons are in a Toolbar window, so it appears they don't have their own window.  Is there any way to send a command to a program to select these buttons in a toolbar window?

Comment: @KennyBrown Yes. Please go thru the documentation of AutoIT.

Comment: I didn't realize how much I could do with this program.  Thanks for the help.  Definitely new to this kind of thing, so I appreciate the support!